# When to use Curves for photo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photo-editing, color-theory, color-grading

i don't understand something in color correction, when should i use **Curves** that changes **Shadows/Highlights** colors, rather than change the color itself by using for example **selective color**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop, like most Adobe applications, offers 2 or 3 ways to achieve many things.

You can use Curves, or Levels, or Selective Color, or Adjustment Layers, etc.

When to choose one method over the other is *entirely* up to the user and their preferred workflow. In some instances one method *may* work better given particular subject matter.

Most often, there's no "absolute" reason to use one method over another.